# Components and events after an external library has changed dom structure

Tags: reactjs

Here is scenario:

- react renders components
- external library changes dom structure and move a part to somewhere else in dom not handled by react

Result:

- Every events set are not working anymore and exceptions..

Expected

- Events (clicks) work

What do you think about it ?

Is it possible with react to rerender everything based of a new dom structure ?

Dom react structure is really changed, some part have moved somewhere else in DOM

Thanks,

Julien

Comment: Aren't you just describing simple routing? With a new route often a completely new dom has to be rendered.

Comment: a specific jquery plugin reorganises dom from an original structure to another one quite different. in this new structure a react dom node has been move to another new branch of dom created by this plugin

Comment: Aha. As you were saying, I think you will have some issues with React knowing when to re-render since manipulating the DOM with jQuery without notifying React can be problematic. React can definitely re-render such DOM-restructures, but you have to emit it somehow. Maybe it is possible to create a speciel event for this case, which lets React know about the major restructure. This is strictly in theory, haven't dealt myself with such DOM alterations with jQuery together with React.

Comment: my first option was to apply new routines after DOM has been changed with external library but it is really not the right philosophy of such a framework use., so I have redone job for not changing DOM structure.